# Scrapy; Trying to scrape the following pages in amazon

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

im trying to scrape all reviews from this amazon product [The link is here](https://www.amazon.com/Apple-MacBook-MC700LL-13-3-Inch-VERSION/product-reviews/B002QQ8H8I/ref=cm_cr_dp_d_show_all_btm?ie=UTF8&reviewerType=all_reviews). However it only render the result of the first page.

[Snapshot of the first page result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jSlKH.png)

below is my code in scrapy framework.

```
import scrapy
from..items import AmazonItem

class SpideramazonSpider(scrapy.Spider):
name = 'spideramazon'
allowed_domains = ['amazon.co.uk, amazon.com']
start_urls = ['https://www.amazon.com/Apple-MacBook-MC700LL-13-3-Inch-VERSION/product-reviews/B002QQ8H8I/ref=cm_cr_dp_d_show_all_btm?ie=UTF8&reviewerType=all_reviews']


def parse(self, response):
    items= AmazonItem()
    getpage = response.css('div[data-hook=review]')
    for get_data in getpage:
        id = get_data.xpath('@id').extract()
        title = get_data.xpath('.//a[@data-hook="review-title"]/span/text()').extract()
        author_name = get_data.css('span.a-profile-name::text').extract()
        review_text = '\n'.join(get_data.xpath('.//span[@data-hook="review-body"]/span/text()').extract())
        stars = self.extract_stars(get_data)
        review_date = get_data.css('span.review-date::text').extract_first()

        items['id'] = id
        items['title'] = title
        items['author_name'] = author_name
        items['review_text'] = review_text
        items['stars'] = stars
        items['review_date'] = review_date
        yield items
    next_page = response.css('li.a-last a::attr(href)').get()
    if next_page is not None:
        next_page=response.urljoin(next_page)
        yield response.follow(url=next_page, callback=self.parse)

def extract_stars(self, get_data):
    stars = None
    star_classes = get_data.css('i.a-icon-star::attr(class)').extract_first().split(' ')
    for i in star_classes:
        if i.startswith('a-star-'):
            stars = int(i[7:])
            break
    return stars
```

im very new to scrapy,any help or guidance is appreciated!

Comment: Can you clarify what specifically your question is? Have you done any debugging?

Comment: yes i have tried to debug, so far there is no error i can find, it just that i have been following the tutorial for scrapy documentation, it should have been able to extract the following pages. However, the scrapy are only able to return the result of the first page of amazon reviews.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the links of the following pages, add them to a queue of links that need to be parsed, and keep checking that queue for more pages to scrape.

You can learn more about this technique here: https://medium.com/quick-code/python-scrapy-tutorial-for-beginners-03-how-to-go-to-the-next-page-d29827e0544b